# Does a poster get notified if an edit is made to an answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

Does a poster get notified if an edit is made to an answer, or should I add a comment to prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edits that other people make to posts which are yours (both questions and answers) will cause an edit notification to show in your inbox.

[image]

However, these notifications are not sent for minor edits. Edits need to be substantiative enough for the system to deem it necessary to notify you. For more information, see Meta.SE:

- [No notification was received for an edit to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post)

> In order to reduce noise sent to users, we only notify when "substantive" changes are happening on their posts.
>
> There are a few rules in how "substantive" is defined, but typically one of the following should be enough to trigger a message:
>
> - edit to a question title
> - the edit in the post body should be over a threshold
> - the edit in code sections should be over another threshold
>
> The threshold varies from site to site. Retagging only is not considered "substantive" hence will not send notification.

Notifications are not sent to the user who asked a question if an answer to their question is edited.

Comment: I swapped my 15-point flag, then ;) I have occasionally wondered why nothing ever happens if I suddenly get a brainstorm on an answer I posted days before, & add what is *actually* the right answer. So, I need to drop a comment into the OP to actually let them know there was a change

Comment: @Tetsujin It's meta, points are irrelevant, [*unless you're Tim!*](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard) Yes, precisely.

Comment: hahaha. I guess so. I always wondered what the Tim references were - I'm still really a newbie ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Not to take anything away from Tim Stone, but every time I see Tim mentioned, I think of Tim Minchin haha

Comment: I was listening to Storm & Prejudice only this afternoon. One of my favourite comedians [if that's what you could label him]

Answer (score 1):

The OP should get a notification whenever a non-trivial edit is made to a post.